# Unable to run ct_netconfc_SUITE testcase

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, common-test, netconf

When I try to run a testcase specified in the test suite ct_netconfc_SUITE, I am getting an error “Failed to start CTH, see the CT Log for details”. What could be the issue? Please give me pointer to resolve the issue. I did not find any clue in the CT log.

```
cd otp\lib\common_test
ct_run -suite test\ct_netconfc_SUITE -case get

Failed: "Failed to start CTH, see the CT Log for details", [{ct_netconfc_SUITE, init_per_suite}]
```

Comment: Could you add the CT log?

Comment: Thanks @2240. I have uploaded the relevant log in G drive https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15RN5lc_pl3xgQZWkpy51IZcenmtqLgCq?usp=sharing Please let me know if you additional logs

Answer (score 2):

How to run the tests in the Erlang/OTP repo is documented [here](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/HOWTO/TESTING.md).

In that documentation it tells you that you should run `make test` to run the tests, so try that and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. I followed the procedure explained in the link shared by you. The original error “Failed to start CTH...." is resolved now. However, I am getting a new error "crypto could not be loaded!". When I debugged it further, I see the module ct_netconfc_SUITE throws this error when it checks whether the module "crypto" is loaded or not. How to resolve this issue?
I am using the command {make common_test_test ARGS="-suite ct_netconfc_SUITE -case get}

Comment: You also need to build the entire Erlang/OTP repo without any applications being disabled. It seems like crypto was not built properly for you, so you need to look into why that is.

Comment: Another query, ct_netconfc_SUITE will act as a Netconf client and tests Netconf operations (I have tried with the Netconf operations "get" & "hello"). Which Netconf server does it try to connect with? Do I need to specify the Netconf Server details (IP, User credentials, etc)?

Comment: Thanks @Lukas. After installing the required packages such as libssl-dev, I ensured that there was no warning thrown by OTP/configure and all modules are loaded. With this. the issue “crypto could not be loaded!” got resolved. I could successfully run {make common_test_test ARGS="-suite ct_netconfc_SUITE}. However, {make common_test_test ARGS="-suite ct_netconfc_SUITE -case get} (i.e, with a testcase) is throwing an error.